# Where can I find Joomla upcoming release dates?

Tags: cms, update

I need to do some third party extension updates on most or all of the Joomla websites I look after.

I am wondering when the next Joomla updates (i.e. Joomla 2.5.21 and Joomla 3.3.1) are planned to be released as I could easily wait a few days, if a Joomla release is imminent, and do the Joomla updates at the same time.

Is there an official page or a forum or similar where I can find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the official roadmap which is posted at http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html.
It gives you the broad picture at which month the minor releases are going to be released

As for patch releases, they are released "as needed". Best bet is to monitor the google groups like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/joomla-dev-cms. Usually something is posted there when we're going to prepare a release. Like currently languages haven been freezed to prepare the release of 3.3.1 / 2.5.21.
Other than that, there is not really an announcement for those patch releases.

Answer (score 1):

Future updates of Joomla will be on these dates:

- V. 3.4 -> July 2014
- V. 3.5 -> 2014-09
- V. 3.11 -> (Fall 2015)
- V. 4.0 -> 2015-03
- V. 4.1 -> 2015-09
- V. 4.2 -> 2016-03
- V. 4.5 -> 2016-09

You can see dates and estimates of future updates of Joomla on these links:
http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_CMS_versions
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla#Version_history

Comment: Just an fyi currently wikipedia is out of date. It notes the LTS for 3.5 which will not happen (as per the other link you posted on docs.joomla.org). This roadmap is also much more recent: http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html

Comment: Thanks Tim! I am especially interested in the next security / bug fix release as in 2.5.21 and 3.3.1 which are the next releases according to: http://developer.joomla.org/development-status.html - I have updated the question accordingly.